# Environment URL '' is not a valid http(s) URL, so it will not be shown as a link in the workflow graph

Tags: github-actions

I got this error in my github action workflow:

> Environment URL '' is not a valid http(s) URL, so it will not be shown
> as a link in the workflow graph.

I can still see the changes of my website after deployment. Just that I am not sure why I have this error in the committed workflow in master branch. The `pages build and deployment` workflow is without error though.

```
0s Run actions/deploy-pages@main Fetching artifact metadata for "github-pages" in this workflow run Found 0 artifact(s) Error: Fetching artifact metadata failed. Is githubstatus.com reporting issues with API requests, Pages, or Actions? Please re-run the deployment at a later time. Error: Error: No artifacts named "github-pages" were found for this workflow run. Ensure artifacts are uploaded with actions/artifact@v4 or later.
    at getArtifactMetadata (/home/runner/work/_actions/actions/deploy-pages/main/src/internal/api-client.js:85:1)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at Deployment.create (/home/runner/work/_actions/actions/deploy-pages/main/src/internal/deployment.js:66:1)
    at main (/home/runner/work/_actions/actions/deploy-pages/main/src/index.js:30:1) Error: Error: No artifacts named "github-pages" were found for this workflow run. Ensure artifacts are uploaded with actions/artifact@v4 or later.
```

This is a public github repo which you can check out the error at https://github.com/ngaisteve1/abby/actions

Here's the workflow:

```yaml
# Simple workflow for deploying static content to GitHub Pages
name: Deploy static content to Pages

on:
  # Runs on pushes targeting the default branch
  push:
    branches: ["master"]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# Sets permissions of the GITHUB_TOKEN to allow deployment to GitHub Pages
permissions:
  contents: read
  pages: write
  id-token: write

# Allow one concurrent deployment
concurrency:
  group: "pages"
  cancel-in-progress: true

jobs:
  # Single deploy job since we're just deploying
  deploy:
    environment:
      name: github-pages
      url: ${{ steps.deployment.outputs.page_url }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Setup Pages
        uses: actions/configure-pages@v1
      - name: Upload artifact
        uses: actions/upload-pages-artifact@v1
        with:
          # Upload entire repository
          path: '.'
      - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
        id: deployment
        uses: actions/deploy-pages@main
```

update yaml file

```
# Simple workflow for deploying static content to GitHub Pages
name: Deploy static content to Pages

on:
  # Runs on pushes targeting the default branch
  push:
    branches: ["master"]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# Sets permissions of the GITHUB_TOKEN to allow deployment to GitHub Pages
permissions:
  contents: read
  pages: write
  id-token: write

# Allow one concurrent deployment
concurrency:
  group: "pages"
  cancel-in-progress: true

jobs:
  # Single deploy job since we're just deploying
  deploy:
    environment:
      name: github-pages
      url: ${{ steps.deployment.outputs.page_url }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4.0.0
      - name: Setup Pages
        uses: actions/configure-pages@v4.0.0
      - name: Upload artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4.0.0
        with:
          # Upload entire repository
          path: '.'
      - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
        id: deployment
        uses: actions/deploy-pages@v2
```

Comment: I just checked this [workflow run](https://github.com/ngaisteve1/abby/actions/runs/7522368933) and that's a warning, not an error. From this error "**Fetching artifact metadata failed. Is githubstatus.com reporting issues with API requests, Pages, or Actions? Please re-run the deployment at a later time.**", it sounds like there might be an issue with these services. Please deploy another instance and see if that works fine

Comment: You need to use the latest versions of those actions in your workflow i.e. https://github.com/actions/configure-pages, https://github.com/actions/upload-pages-artifact, and https://github.com/actions/deploy-pages. Also, always include your workflow in your question.

Comment: Solved after re-creating the workflow. Thanks